# How to detect the Actionscript of a SWF File?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash, actionscript-2, detect

If I have just a SWF file but not the .FLA file, how can I detect which AciontScript the SWF file was built in?

Having difficulty in working out if my SWF file was built in AS2 or AS3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggested Methods:

- If you just need to check the `SWF`, you can use the online tool at : http://blog.sitedaniel.com/2009/11/swf-info-width-height-swf-version-actionscript-version-framerate/
- If you need to use AS for it, you need to load the SWF and find out if it's a AVM1Movie or not  You will need a piece of code like :

  `trace(loader.content is AVM1Movie);
  // true = AS1/2, false = AS3`

This will be `true` if the AS is AS1 or AS2 and `false` if AS3.

P.S. : If you want to use it in an application there is a `SWFReader.as` that gets almost any information out of a SWF. The source is located at :
http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/utils/SWFReader.as